# SQL Server differential backup to SQL statements

Tags: sql-server, backup, binlog

Is there any way to convert differential backup to SQL statements which will produce identical results when applied?

Or any other solution similar to binary log in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

SQL Server differential backups contain those pages that have been changed since the last full backup.

This will be completely unrelated to SQL DML statements that have been run and the data can not be extracted.

What are you trying to do though?

Comment: I was trying to import data to MySQL and then do periodical synchronization the same direction. Looks DTS is way to go?

Comment: Yes, DTS or SSIS from DB to DB